Cache firebase function output to reduce database calls
I have implemented a leaderboard using  firebase firestore and functions. I want to cache the output of the function/or bypass it and serve applications using this function through cache. Let's say I cache it for 3 hours. Is there a method to achieve this on firebase using callable functions? and My app is built with flutter.
exports.getScores = functions
    .runWith({
        enforceAppCheck: true, // Reject requests with missing or invalid App Check tokens.
    })
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        console.log('enforceAppCheck');
        try {
            const scoreQ = await admin.firestore().collection("players")
                .orderBy("score", "desc")
                .limit(7)
                .get();

            return scoreQ.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    player: doc.id,
                    score: doc.data().score,
                    level: doc.data().level,
                };
            });

        } catch (e) {
            functions.logger.log("error occured", e);
            return (e);
        }
    });


I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for.  You can always store the results of the query in memory and reuse them right?

Cache in CDN and access from that maybe

Nothing is built into Cloud Functions or Firestore for that specific use-case, but you can build it yourself pretty easily.

First make sure that caching is enabled. It's enabled by default, so there's nothing you need to do unless you turned it off before.
Now when you run the Firestore query, the data will be cached on the device.
At this point, also write the current timestamp somewhere to some form of local storage.
Then whenever you want to load the data, check if the timestamp from local storage is less than 3 hours ago.

If it is less than 3 hours ago, force loading the data from the cache by specifying source: Source.cache
If it is older than 3 hours, load the data from the server as usual - which will also update the cache.



Note: the option to force get data from the cache was only recently added to the Firestore API, so be sure to use a recent version of the SDK.

Thanks, but if we can cache on function, it will read 1s for all users. Say there are 1000 users, firestore approach will read the leaderboard 1000 times while the function cache will only read from Firestore 1 time to serve 1000 users.

Yup, that's also possible - but that means your function will need to return the leaderboard. --- Another alternative is to use a data bundle with the top result, which means you read once from the database and then serve the same bundle to all clients. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles
